# How do I specify a Diesel DATABASE_URL when my password contains an at-sign (@)?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am getting started with Diesel by following their [official documentation](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/). I also have PostgreSQL installed. My database username is `postgres` and the password is `1schoollife@`.

I started with

```
$ echo DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:1schoollife@@localhost/diesel_demo > .env
$ diesel setup
```

results:

```
Creating migrations directory at: /home/naufil/Desktop/rust/3june/testing/migrations
Creating database: diesel_demo
database "diesel_demo" already exists
```

I created a migration:

```
$ diesel migration generate create_posts
Creating migrations/2019-06-03-182531_create_posts/up.sql
Creating migrations/2019-06-03-182531_create_posts/down.sql
```

I get the following error when migrating the database:

```
$ diesel migration run
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ConnectionError(BadConnection("could not translate host name \"@localhost\" to address: Name or service not known\n"))', src/libcore/result.rs:997:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DATABASE_URL` you have provided is not the URL you are attempting to use. `@` is a special character that separates the credentials from the hostname. Since your credentials contain an `@`, it needs to be URL escaped:

```
postgres://postgres:1schoollife%40@localhost/diesel_demo
```

Diesel maintainer [sgrif said](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/871#issuecomment-298227608):

> Yes, percent encoding is 100% the correct thing for us to be doing.

This was implemented in [PR 1058](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/pull/1058)